# Datagrid with button redo/undo for the cell change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hi I want create 2 button Redo and Undo.

I am thinking of creating two stacks to handle the change into a Datagrid. But I don't know the event to manage the changed value into the cell(after focus).

My xaml code Datagrid:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_Car"  Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Constructor" Header="Constructor"  Width="*" Binding="{Binding _constructor, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Model" Header="Model" Width="*" Binding="{Binding model}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Price" Header="Price" Width="*" Binding="{Binding price}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Into ModelView the definition

```
private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars = null;
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get { return _cars; }
        set
        {
            _cars = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

My implementation for NotifyPropertyChanged():

```
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a way to bind the event after editing a cell to a command, you should go with an Eventtrigger.

Just add the binding to the trigger in your xaml:

```
      <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_Car"  Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Constructor" Header="Constructor"  Width="*" Binding="{Binding _constructor, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Model" Header="Model" Width="*" Binding="{Binding model}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Price" Header="Price" Width="*" Binding="{Binding price}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And add a command to your ViewModel.
If you use mvvmlight you could just create a RelayCommand and do whatever you like with that.

Comment: Thank you very much but I don't want to use Toolkit or Framework. I started learning VMMV recently and at this stage I would like to understand as much as possible by creating everything myself.